# luatex img library bbox - returning image extents

Tags: luatex, lua, pdfcrop

I'm having some issues running `pdfcrop` and some other pdf utilities on my work machine and am trying to take matters into my own hands. I want to crop a page of a pdf document, similar to what `pdfcrop sample.pdf` would do. I thought I would try `luatex`'s `img` library, but I might be misinterpreting what is meant by bounding box.

Using `img.scan({filename='sample.pdf',page=1,pagebox='art'}).bbox`, I thought the bounding box of the ink on the page would be returned, but the size (in sp) of the page is returned.

How would I return the bounding box of an image?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

Hello.

\begin{luacode*}
 bbox = img.scan({filename='sample.pdf',page=1,pagebox='art'}).bbox
 -- tried: none, media, crop, bleed, trim, art
 for i, v in ipairs(bbox) do
    tex.print(v..',')
 end
\end{luacode*}

\includegraphics[trim={5cm 5cm 5cm 5cm}, clip]{sample.pdf} % manual trimming

% I want to use the bounding box value 
\includegraphics[trim={20000000sp 0 0 0}, clip]{sample.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `artbox` is set inside the PDF file; it can be any value that the initial author choose (so probably just the same as the page size). I don't think that there's any built in function to get the actual bounding box from the connect; you'll probably have to implement it yourself using `pdfscanner`.

Comment: @MaxChernoff is correct. The "artbox" is a (pun intended) term or art. In commercial printing from PDF, it is an area on a page, that is reserved for additional content. That is, the `artbox` is where the image from ArtistX will be placed onto the page layout created by ArtistY. So, Artist Y has to define the `artbox`, and ArtistX has to design so that it fits. More likely than not, your PDF has no `artbox`, so it defaults to entire page. If it did have an `artbox` of your creation, it probably would not be what you intend.

Comment: Aside from artbox, I tried all other options to no avail. I'm looking into pdfscanner and pdfe as well.

Comment: Do you have the sample.pdf somewhere available to look at?

Comment: @topskip see: https://www.overleaf.com/3115695146fkqrxkfjqgxk#27f164

Comment: The output is what I'd expect. Your PDF has two boxes: CropBox and MediaBox both with exact the same dimensions: `[0.0 0.0 612.0 792.0]` which is what your output shows.